# nginx [emerge] duplicate zone "WORDPRESS" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress:1

Tags: wordpress, nginx, virtualhost

I am currently trying to run a virtual host nginx config with two sites. www.christiandigits.com and rccglp1.org I have the dns setup on digital ocean but on running this command "nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t" i get the following message "nginx [emerge] duplicate zone "WORDPRESS" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress:1" with the subsequent line telling me that the nginx.conf test failed.

Can you kindly tell me where to look as to tackle this error message or what lines i need to edit in my vhost server blocks?

Thanks for any kind help

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Actually its not. Its a problem im currently facing with having to serve two domains off a single droplet on digital ocean and its this part that has me wracking my brains out.

Comment: How is that not off topic? Server configuration isn't considered on topic here. You should try serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Hmm..my bad. Thanks for the heads up on that